# When i upload image from local machine into TINYMCE then its showing " Got a bad response from the server" error

Tags: html

When I upload image from local machine into TINYMCE then its showing " Got a bad response from the server" error 
its create a tinymce_assets file in which a tomcat error code is showing instead of file description

```
<html>
<head> //Here all requirement plugins added 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/plugin.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>//body part
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea id="instructions" name="content" style="width:100%">
  </textarea>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//here script code in which tinymce and required functions are added

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theame: "advanced",
    plugins: [ "save","uploadimage","link image",
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    setup:function(ed){
         ed.on('keydown', function(e) { 
               console.log("keydown");

              });    
    },

    height:"75%",
    toolbar: " save | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image uploadimage",`enter code here`



});





function myFileBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {

    var cmsURL = window.location.toString();    // script URL - use an absolute path!
    if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
        //add the type as the only query parameter
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
    }
    else {
        //add the type as an additional query parameter
        // (PHP session ID is now included if there is one at all)
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
    }

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file : cmsURL,
        title : 'My File Browser',
        width : 420,  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
        height : 400,
        resizable : "yes",
        inline : "yes",  // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
        close_previous : "no"
    }, {
        window : win,
        input : field_name
    });
    return false;
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: YA sure,Miki... Actully when i take a image from my machine or local machine then it is not populated in tinymce editor and showing bad server response
I am sharing a link in which image upload from local machine into tinymce and i want just like that link is:
http://murmuring-lowlands-1342.herokuapp.com/ 
please help me